# Vue: dynamically remove component: the last component is removed instead of the first, wrong component removed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Code fiddlie: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-austin-ty6f7i?file=/src/App.vue

I have a simple page that allows user to change 3 inputs and add 3 images:

**App.vue**:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(line, i) in this.lines" class="line-wrapper" v-bind:key="i">
      <AddImageComponent
        class="add-image"
        matchType="image.*"
        selectButtonText="SELECT OR DROP AN IMAGE"
      />

      <input type="text" v-model="this.lines[i].text" />

      <div class="delete-button" v-on:click.stop="this.lines.splice(i, 1)">
        Delete
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AddImageComponent from "./AddImageComponent.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    AddImageComponent: AddImageComponent,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      lines: [{ text: "A" }, { text: "B" }, { text: "C" }],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  height: 100vh;
}

.add-image {
  background-color: lime !important;
  height: 50%;
}

.line-wrapper {
  background-color: purple;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.delete-button {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.delete-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
}

input {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
}
</style>
```

The first page I see is this:

[image]

When I add the images:

[image]

When I click the first (topmost) `Delete` red button:

[image]

So what happens, is that while the texts of the remaining elements are `B`, and `C`, (text `A` was deleted), the pictures are birds and the snake, instead of snake and dog (the last `AddImageComponent` was removed, instead of the first).

I'm not sure as to what is the best practice way of solving this.

Comment: Immediately I see you're doing `:key="i"`. Binding key to index is usually a bad idea because the index of an element will change when you delete or rearrange elements in the array. Choose (or make) something that won't change for each item.

Comment: using :key=“i” isn’t the problem. You need to do a few things. One stop using splice for such a scenario. Two using a unique property in the array to delete the items not i. I’m on mobile device right now later in the day I may provide a solution. Just tag me to remind me about this.

Comment: Why is using `splice` bad? I thought the problem is that `AddImageComponent` isn't tied to any particular element in the `lines` array, thus when the size of the `lines` array decreases, the last `AddImageComponent` doesn't get displayed

Comment: @SamsonIyanda If you could show a solution, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Using the `key` is exactly the problem. It literally tells Vue: *"the unique identifier for this array element is its position in the array"*. So when you remove element at position `0` in an array with 3 elements Vue will keep the first and the second element (because keys `0` and `1` are still in the array, so they haven't changed) and will remove the last element, the one with `index: 2`, because it's gone from the array. Give each element a unique identifier, whether it's an `uuid.v4()` or the filename and use it as `:key`.

Comment: `key` literally means: "what this item is tracked by". For performance reasons, Vue doesn't track an item's equality deeply (unless specifically told to do so). It keeps the initially rendered DOM element (and eventually moves it around in DOM if its position in the array changes) and only cares about its `key`. When the `key` changes, Vue understands it no longer deals with the same element and updates accordingly.

Comment: Using key isn’t the problem @tao. Binding the key to the index value is the problem. Also splice isn’t the right approach to this. I’ll provide a working solution right about now.

Comment: *"Binding the key to the index value is the problem"* and *"using `:key="i"` isn't the problem"* cannot be both **true** at the same time and are statements you've made here. Don't bother providing a working solution, I'm not the one who needs help here. I'm the one who spotted false statements disguised as *"advice"* and I wanted to clarify it so OP doesn't get confused. Besides, there's nothing wrong with using `splice` on arrays in Vue. On the contrary, it is actually the recommended (more performant) way of removing/replacing items from arrays, especially when dealing with large arrays.

Comment: @tao I'm sorry if you feel upset with my statement. I feel you saying using key is a bad thing which it isn't. It is necessary for performance and DOM updates. Not meaning to disregard with you said. Also, regarding using splice, it mutates the array it acts upon and this is very bad. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: 1. I'm not upset at all. 2. Using `index` as `key` is exactly the same as not using a `key` at all. When not providing a `key`, Vue internally uses the `index` as `key` and issues a warning about the fact this is potentially problematic since it won't be able to correctly detect removal of items or reordering items in the array. Using the `index` as `key` is actually a declaration to Vue: *"I'm fine with you not being able to detect array mutations or reordering, I don't need it in this case."*.

Comment: @samson, lastly, you seem to confuse the principle of immutability with reactivity. Vue docs list `splice()` as a proper and recognised [array mutation method](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#array-change-detection). Please provide any official and canonical documentation for your statement: *"mutating an array in Vue 3 is very bad"*. I'm asking you to do it because, as far as I'm aware of, that statement is ***false***.

Comment: @tao thanks for bringing docs to my notification. I'm aware of what I'm saying and sure about it. under the same doc you referenced have you seen this part https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#replacing-an-array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253509/discussion-between-samson-iyanda-and-tao).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having a `key` that is not the `line`'s array index. Add a unique `id` member to each `line` member, and use that as the `key` prop:

```js
data() {
  return {
    lines: [
      { id: 1, text: 'A' },
      { id: 2, text: 'B' },
      { id: 3, text: 'C' }
    ],
  };
},
```

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(line, i) in this.lines" class="line-wrapper" v-bind:key="line.id">
```

[Live example](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqdGGtT20bwr1ycdmwYJBuSPkYlaQiQlDaBDCH9EjKZs3SybtBrpJPBYfjv3d07nU6yIaQDY0t7+759+nZ0UJb+shGjYLSvRFamXImXlzlj+5Fc0oN+ZEsvLqoXl6NJKnOxw+QWkzlTiax9BNSXIxamvK4BA9+964qXpagAvPTmMo+CK7EyZ76MLkeGNTA/iKKTjC/EYZGVRS5y1Z4wy5FHkScR53LUHWZchcnFqhSAQIf+tntci1SE6nWjVJFfiBsFWB+P3x0fXrCzc3Z0fvaBHZyyk/cHb487qiloZfWSedkoprQABRzIlqyIRIoAa/ln+cU3xz16dFprANAIJbw5aUN8ijwIUxle+bUqyh4/vy7hQEzkDtvdchzF2BFxsQKmzg3Z5/Zpf+rcJrzWYSVLBc8SvFwptuZ1FldFxsb+dO0Ew2P8x2UubogyEjFvUsVuUVzOMxGwMQTReAffw5aoDjQCW5cUrIOI9o4+I674ZKslroRqqrx9Y4w8FLDPt0xGAdvdYeh5VGAM5ExD9yz0tQN9ZqGHAP1CskAm2KUl49P+1LoJXaZWKXrvKUSy1mDOw6tFVTR55IVFWlQBaFtdhSueE5tEyEUCEnZns2UCkDtk49vgvY9HKjPBnuh74bnqsfpl9rNl5ObVfbzKpipTQSzmRRUJAO2VN6wuUhmxeQr4dJbxaiFzD0IPzkVmRfTi9D4ZlYiISQmWyXwBSpY3huuNdy0jlbR6t0p4FY9kA/e2OzOo68pprhvUCJJi2RocNlVNZhYyV6LSrNYUVBXP65JXEFgPCsNwJYLrRCp0GknXeU/itJtctddkrUSaFteb/fE943OIfS0VAs8E22hntDEBN9ZnW18ovryo4gv4KMqu+roVvEVORKrP2lrR4bRpZusWMGORhIrEV57MMQIZT+Ui90LQC27FCPI4OaWrpK9QF7w3v6zE0inqcED1rsiP4GEDQVsLEYEvzgByTPR9zFTwJdXlDvUdgga4UGO1IYQna8RbiAi5sj/ZWNbkM4B4KHrMoDqMW+quQz3CeYCV8rlIobLLGNAgnaldWbq5yoeO1B3KNgWn0N/errUvdgdh0p73e1MsU5SEpbgNBXh9FSY8XyCkyA/p0TSotnuQvoOGtd56ExlFYk11Nwbcprv0RFrbDoXv1PtbZlCJUTvM0Eawu47SsX1fZgsW1FXo2MJTbN+ONwGnZw2QzauN7y5EVzXnRshN2IXhtRIZxMAb8uXL8+P3Z/8e7081ieO0/9VyH2qcw1zf0EZ1XywhXbqmOgyPgH1UFRQf09bsbDSApwWP3kCfRzMtL0aBFLDXRQFplRtU6MRaX31bbb8032BmKJIihTpG+geMvuBUn1OAmpOBmJ5CjpS8SdOeFPz8/kRgImqsHUcQN80DFnMISXuIyfKpSh2CbgSgki9UUkSdowdlqNMDzFmvKS/IV8SwY9ky6QrUd7mQzhvZYMeOmzxUEkJ5IhxGgkbJD4DBFxyPJ1uGA56ZMnykve0cLXlFTqlBrPDR1xfYPmMo3QS2iKRoWAmIbwyfCZ1+nn1BVj9kjDZF16SeBX1VFDRfoQZKTKcMsreBganI0xV8CKJg17w2OSGixyjs6jJAcRSSMZs8QZiPoetTVk2IrU2wLQedQaESlZqMT/IlVMhIq4akT8adw9sQtgBb2NF+0AVyChyQi2uGOp0TYHBhywxDDRQZ+t6EN3odnnpuI9X+/nh2CnGCGSjjFdnrYyna6vij0XobcYpFz0qto49fB/URRMyn83fadY46Fg0uChihRhvDlkzKfD0hO/deiRoC1fGazlN6YthlOhY0tjlO+ElkEm5BD0UwlEF7p+AfwwpAAYoHwyjo6v96dhrdxrgF/VCgP7BYsDosShEBBPj0xpD75m64+InnXfx1cn709fXB4T9vz88+nR5t9VcH8sW2ZhEXufJinsl0ha2mkjzVFtBBLb9B3dyFodiSgbbbAY+hqdPTXMDKb/zsXYv5lYRppbhBSppzzXwLIOIKu/G3h84fIjXcFS+9BDYfGC8SZfeNxZxPZjvM/OuLsxRFEyZeyGEKb7CJ2JEa/Ioz14/50sRvO6DP3CXhaRzH+n1tCbE+vTZr2xw6o4HbrWAX1gL2rN0NyqKWmAy4TsHIIJc9td2dZ135p7/t7c2eo3LdwvKZhsExZuH4iybsRPA5rD0NrTh48A3GuEjcBMzbJV2gY4RSQYxoe82sN3Bmb+wn/rhOewQOmIZbZD0lazRnK9Y7oeWvh0lvnhZmLQWblYS7bLlmMHyaKmb2Smu0bwZTEtHTeEM+GGSTyH0SV4lNpIPJ937ihy3QzHC2JQ7T7TbGdu1S+jT+Ff/+2J4+LKN1KG9UYW4UN+8W/Ltxs7ONa9AQcW+mF1LHvYalsRyXv/tCMN7Dv946+xwsiXidiMik1/uDk9Ovb85OL3TKbuKiLTZZd0+Wfjw+PDu9P03tfq0r2dDKZ8bKnkOeO6Zn8EOIAZsQbaGDyG2vcOOqbX4wWOO1kdNjfrbQ0no7YifD5Tf86Wigw6aYfvDnKEeNTbT9jf8RTNZ+4bj7D14FX0Q=)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments using **key** isn't the problem but how it's been used. Binding the **key** to **index** value of your iteration isn't an ideal thing to do. Also using **splice** and **this** keyword in the templates isn’t ideal in this case.

Notice in your script section. **lines** is an array of objects with **text** being the only property. Ideally, there should be a unique property to bind **key** to such as an **id**. so I'll propose two solutions.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(line, i) in lines" class="line-wrapper" v-bind:key="line.text">
      <AddImageComponent
        class="add-image"
        matchType="image.*"
        selectButtonText="SELECT OR DROP AN IMAGE"
      />

      <input type="text" v-model="lines[i].text" />

      <div class="delete-button" v-on:click.stop="onDelete(line)">Delete</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Notice I remove **this** keyword in the template and also bind **key** to the **text** property of each items in **lines**. Also notice the onDelete method I provided in the script.

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    AddImageComponent: AddImageComponent,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      lines: [{ text: "A" }, { text: "B" }, { text: "C" }],
    };
  },
  methods: {
  // take note of this
    onDelete(item) {
      this.lines = this.lines.filter((line) => line.text !== item.text);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Now this solution assume your unique property in **lines** is **text**. Another thing you can do is to use **id** as a unique property and use it in place of **text**.
In Summary, here's the solution also notice I took off the v-model in use. It can actually results into problems for you. There are several ways of using v-model inside loops but not the way you've handled it. I suggest you do some reading here https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(line, i) in lines" class="line-wrapper" v-bind:key="line.text">
      <AddImageComponent
        class="add-image"
        matchType="image.*"
        selectButtonText="SELECT OR DROP AN IMAGE"
      />

      <input type="text" :value="lines[i].text" @blur="(e) => onEdit(e, line)" />

      <div class="delete-button" v-on:click.stop="onDelete(line)">Delete</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AddImageComponent from "./AddImageComponent.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    AddImageComponent: AddImageComponent,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      lines: [{ text: "A" }, { text: "B" }, { text: "C" }],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onEdit(e, item) {
      const value = e.target.value;
      this.lines = this.lines.map((line) => {
        if (line.text === item.text) {
          return {
            ...line,
            text: value,
          };
        }
        return line;
      });
    },
    onDelete(item) {
      this.lines = this.lines.filter((line) => line.text !== item.text);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  height: 100vh;
}

.add-image {
  background-color: lime !important;
  height: 50%;
}

.line-wrapper {
  background-color: purple;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.delete-button {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.delete-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
}

input {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
}
</style>
```

the other solution is just the same except this time. I'm modifying **lines** to have a unique property such as an **id**. I personally recommend you follow this approach.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(line, i) in lines" class="line-wrapper" v-bind:key="line.id">
      <AddImageComponent
        class="add-image"
        matchType="image.*"
        selectButtonText="SELECT OR DROP AN IMAGE"
      />

      <input type="text" :value="lines[i].text" @blur="(e) => onEdit(e, id)" />

      <div class="delete-button" v-on:click.stop="onDelete(line.id)">Delete</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AddImageComponent from "./AddImageComponent.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    AddImageComponent: AddImageComponent,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      lines: [{ id: 1, text: "A" }, { id: 2, text: "B" }, { id: 3, text: "C" }],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onEdit(e, id) {
      const value = e.target.value;
      this.lines = this.lines.map((line) => {
        if (line.id === item.id) {
          return {
            ...line,
            text: value,
          };
        }
        return line;
      });
    },
    onDelete(id) {
      this.lines = this.lines.filter((line) => line.id !== id);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  height: 100vh;
}

.add-image {
  background-color: lime !important;
  height: 50%;
}

.line-wrapper {
  background-color: purple;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.delete-button {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.delete-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
}

input {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
}
</style>
```

for docs and references you can check out vue docs. https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html